# eclipse gdb - how to step into a MACRO containing lines of code

Tags: eclipse, gdb

I'm using `Kinetis Design Studio, Version: 3.2.0`

```
#define DECODE_QSTR qstr qst = 0; \
    do { \
        qst = (qst << 7) + (*ip & 0x7f); \
    } while ((*ip++ & 0x80) != 0)
```

When I step-into the line `DECODE_QSTR;` it will not step into the `do-while` loop.

```
MARK_EXC_IP_SELECTIVE();
DECODE_QSTR;
PUSH(mp_load_name(qst));
DISPATCH();
```

Is there a way to enable stepping-into MACROs containing multiple lines of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this.  This is either a limitation in DWARF or a limitation in compilers, depending on your view.

In theory a compiler could emit entries in the line table for each relevant part of the macro.  However, I don't know of any compiler that does this (this is the compiler limitation part).  And, if it were done, it would still leave open the question of how to see the macro arguments while stepping (DWARF doesn't provide any way to do this).

A workaround is to use inline functions, though of course that isn't always possible.